# Perl - regex How to write this in python?

Tags: python, regex, perl

I wrote the following `regex` in `perl` and now i want to write it in `python`.

```
if ($textline =~ /^([A-Z0-9]+:)(.*)/)
```

Comment: I've edited your question to add code tags.

Comment: This is the definition of too localized. Since there is no description of what this regex is trying to do, there is no way another person trying to do the same thing could find this question.

Comment: That means : if variable $textline match the beginning of UPPER case word (one or more characters) + : + anything with some (captures)

Comment: I think the perl reg expression is sufficient as description. I'm trying to match every line that doesn't start with a space and everything after a ":"

Comment: It's clear for Perl coders ;) Perl is the best language to perform REGEXes. I love Python for other things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> textline = "AZERTY:qwerty"
>>> if re.search('^([A-Z0-9]+:)(.*)', textline):
...     print("match !")
```

http://docs.python.org/library/re.html

If you have problems using the interactive python interpreter, copy/paste this in your terminal :

```
cd /tmp
wget http://sputnick-area.net/ftp/downloads/re.py
chmod +x re.py
./re.py
```

**Edit**: this is an example that should fit your needs :

```
#!/usr/bin/python2
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-

# $ cat /tmp/dmesg
# AZERTY:qwerty01
# AZERTY:qwerty02
# zzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
# AZERTY:qwerty03

import re

f = open("/tmp/dmesg", "r")
for textline in f.readlines():
    if re.search('^([A-Z0-9]+:)(.*)', textline):
        print "match "+textline.rstrip('\n')

f.close()
```

Comment: That's not what `sys.ps2` looks like :P

Comment: You have good eyes, I edit my POST Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams =)

Comment: that doesn't give me any return. It matches 0 line

Comment: See my edited POST above

Comment: yes but your solution will search through the string for a matching when the "^" means to match it only at the beginning of the string. shouldn't be re.match instead of re.search?

Comment: See what's fits better your needs : http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#search-vs-match

Comment: so this should work fine? ('^([A-Z0-9]+:)(.*)', textline): I'm new to python. so the regex syntax is the same for python and for perl?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9294/discussion-between-newlearner-and-sputnick)